# implement yum functions from kickstar (ks.cfg) file for rh/centos install

Tags: post, centos, yum

I've got the following kickstart file (ks.cfg) for a raw centos installation. I'm trying to implement a "%post" process that will allow the installation to be modified, using you functions (install, groupremove, etc). The whole ks file is at the end of the issue.

I'm not sure why, but the following kickstart is not running the yum install mysql, yum install mysql-server in the post process.

After the install, entering "service mysql start" results in the err msg saying mysql is not found. I am, however, able to run the yum install cmds after installation, and mysql gets installed.

I know I'm missing something subtle, but not sure what it is.

---

```
%post

yum install mysql -y                    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<NOT WORKING!!!!!
yum install mysql-server -y              <<<<<<<<<<<<<<NOT WORKING!!!!!

%end
```

---

Thanks

---

ks.cfg

```
  [root@localhost ~]# cat /root/anaconda-ks.cfg 

  # Kickstart file automatically generated by anaconda.

  #version=DEVEL
  install
  cdrom
  lang en_US.UTF-8
  keyboard us
  network --onboot yes --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp
  rootpw  --iscrypted $1$JCZKA/by$sVSHffsPr3ZDUp6m7c5gt1
  # Reboot after installation
  reboot
  firewall --service=ssh
  authconfig --useshadow --enablemd5
  selinux --enforcing
  timezone --utc America/Los_Angeles
  bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=sda --append=" rhgb crashkernel=auto quiet"
  # The following is the partition information you requested
  # Note that any partitions you deleted are not expressed
  # here so unless you clear all partitions first, this is
  # not guaranteed to work
  #clearpart --all --initlabel

  #part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=200
  #part / --fstype=ext4 --grow --size=3000
  #part swap --grow --maxsize=4064 --size=2032



  repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=cdrom:sr1 --cost=100

  %packages
  @Base
  @Core
  @Desktop
  @Fonts
  @General Purpose Desktop
  @Internet Browser
  @X Window System
  binutils
  gcc
  kernel-devel
  make
  patch
  python

  %end

  %post
  cp /boot/grub/menu.lst /boot/grub/grub.conf.bak
  sed -i 's/ rhgb//' /boot/grub/grub.conf
  cp /etc/rc.d/rc.local /etc/rc.local.backup
  cat >>/etc/rc.d/rc.local <<EOF
  echo
  echo "Installing VMware Tools, please wait..."
  if [ -x /usr/sbin/getenforce ]; then oldenforce=\$(/usr/sbin/getenforce); /usr/sbin/setenforce permissive || true; fi
  mkdir -p /tmp/vmware-toolsmnt0
  for i in hda sr0 scd0; do mount -t iso9660 /dev/\$i /tmp/vmware-toolsmnt0 && break; done
  cp -a /tmp/vmware-toolsmnt0 /opt/vmware-tools-installer
  chmod 755 /opt/vmware-tools-installer
  cd /opt/vmware-tools-installer
  mv upgra32 vmware-tools-upgrader-32
  mv upgra64 vmware-tools-upgrader-64
  mv upgrade.sh run_upgrader.sh
  chmod +x /opt/vmware-tools-installer/*upgr*
  umount /tmp/vmware-toolsmnt0
  rmdir /tmp/vmware-toolsmnt0
  if [ -x /usr/bin/rhgb-client ]; then /usr/bin/rhgb-client --quit; fi
  cd /opt/vmware-tools-installer
  ./run_upgrader.sh
  mv /etc/rc.local.backup /etc/rc.d/rc.local
  rm -rf /opt/vmware-tools-installer
  sed -i 's/3:initdefault/5:initdefault/' /etc/inittab
  mv /boot/grub/grub.conf.bak /boot/grub/grub.conf
  if [ -x /usr/sbin/getenforce ]; then /usr/sbin/setenforce \$oldenforce || true; fi
  if [ -x /bin/systemd ]; then systemctl restart prefdm.service; else telinit 5; fi
  EOF
  /usr/sbin/adduser test
  /usr/sbin/usermod -p '$1$QcRcMih7$VG3upQam.lF4BFzVtaYU5.' test
  /usr/sbin/adduser test1
  /usr/sbin/usermod -p '$1$LMyHixbC$4.aATdKUb2eH8cCXtgFNM0' test1
  /usr/bin/chfn -f 'ruser' root 




  %end

  %post

  yum install mysql -y                    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<NOT WORKING!!!!!
  yum install mysql-server -y              <<<<<<<<<<<<<<NOT WORKING!!!!!

  %end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just put mysql and mysql-server into the `%packages` section, no need to do this in `%post`.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by line-ending when I faced same problem as you. Try to check line-ending of ks.cfg. **It should be LF** not CR+LF or CR.

It will be help you if you;

- Try *system-config-kickstart* tool.
- Find generated */root/anaconda-ks.cfg* though there may be no %post section.

Cheers.